# C programming on a µ-controller: printf() and FDEV_SETUP_STREAM?

Tags: c, file, stream, printf

I have reached two stumbling blocks while programming a calculator program.  Although I am getting the right result from the calculator and printing properly for addition, subtraction and multiplication, I am just printing the `?` symbol for the result of division.  Please refer to the code below.

```
static void calculate(int *val1, int *val2, char *op){
float a = *val1;
float b = *val2;
float c = a/b;

   /*
   A stands for addition, B for sub, C for mul, D for div
   I have already verified that the right operation is being
   performed
   */

if(strcmp(op,"A")==0)
    {
    printf("%i \n\r", *val1+*val2);
}else if(strcmp(op,"B")==0)
    {
    printf("%i \n\r", *val1-*val2);
}else if(strcmp(op,"C")==0)
    {
    printf("%i \n\r", *val1 * *val2);
}else if(strcmp(op,"D")==0)
    {
    printf("%f \n\r", c);
}
}
```

I am using real term to print the results from my atmega 32 microcontroller.

In the debugger, I did confirm that float c has the right value when the operation selected by the user is Division "D" but it did not seem to have a decimal point associated with it although it is a float.

2nd Question:

I was wondering whether I can use an array of chars (a string) like this:

```
//please note that below I am just simulating user keystrokes on a keypad attached to a
//microcontroller just for simplifying the problem.

  char a[20] = {1,2,3,4,5,\n};
  FILE keypad_str = FDEV_SETUP_STREAM(NULL, a, _FDEV_SETUP_READ);
```

What I am trying to above is trying to come up with a strategy to enable me to print out each user key press right away rather than making `keypad_str` the `stdin` and then printing out the entire string of user entered command on the screen.

Comment: Try `(float)*val1 / *val2` in place of `c` in `printf`

Comment: Also in your second code it should be `'\n'`

Comment: @VinayakGarg: Why would the evaluation in the `printf()` call make any difference?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler the problem with your "float c = a/b" (the problem that VinayakGarg fixed) is that "a/b" is from integers to integers, so e.g 1/3 is 0 because that is how integer div works. Casting *val1 to float will cause the compiler to generate a calculation that will result in a proper floating-point answer (e.g. 0.33333...). Another thing that Vinayak's code comment addresses is that 3 of the 4 operators you have are evaluated in the printf, so for symmetry the 4th one, divide, should also be.

Comment: @cardiffspaceman: That's funny: I thought `float a = *val1;` made `a` into a `float` (assigned the value from the `int` which is `*val1`).  Am I missing something?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler float a = *val does mean 'a' is a float. But the  expression on the right of the assignment is evaluated on its own terms and then converted to a float. So VinayakGarg's cast changes the right side so it computes a float.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't checking for divide by zero before you do the division.

It is not clear why you always do a division, even when the operation is an addition or subtraction or multiplication.  You should do the division only when necessary:

```
else if (strcmp(op, "D")==0)
{
    float a = *val1;
    float b = *val2;
    if (*val2 == 0)
        printf("Divide by zero error\n");
    else
    {
        float c = a / b;
        printf("%f\n", c);
    }
}
```

I've left variable `c` in place as it makes it easier to debug the values.

None of this explains the question mark output.

(Do you have to tell the C compiler on the Atmega 32 microcontroller to include support for floating point in the library?  This might account for the question mark.)

I would have chosen the strings `"+"`, `"-"`, `"*"` and `"/"` as mnemonics for the operations; I would not then bother with a comment to explain what the operations mean.

Normally, you would not include a carriage return in the format.  When you do, it conventionally precedes, not follows, the newline.  It also isn't clear why you want a blank at the end of the output lines.

Some of the question about FDEV_SETUP_STREAM() requires knowledge I don't have.

However, the C compiler should tell you that:

```
char a[20] = {1,2,3,4,5,\n};
```

is invalid.  You might mean either of these; they're both valid, but rather different:

```
  char a[20] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, '\n' };
  char a[20] = { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '\n' };
```

The initializers above can be abbreviated to:

```
 char a[20] = "\001\002\003\004\005\n";
 char a[20] = "12345\n";
```

This emphasizes the difference (and no, the double zeroes aren't strictly necessary, but help make the point).

Answer (score 1):

For your question-1, there were multiple problems, so I re-wrote your program into the following

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void calculate(int val1, int val2, char op) 
{
    switch(op) {
        case 'A':
            printf("%d+%d = %d \n", val1, val2, val1 + val2);
            break;
        case 'B':
            printf("%d-%d = %d \n", val1, val2, val1 - val2);
            break;
        case 'C':
            printf("%d*%d = %d \n", val1, val2, val1 * val2);
            break;
        case 'D':
            if (val2 == 0) {
                printf("can't divide by 0\n");
                break;
            }                     
            printf("%d/%d = %.2f \n", val1, val2, (float)val1/(float)val2);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }   

    return;
}  

int main(void) 
{
    int a = 10, b = 20; 
    char op = 'D';
    calculate(a, b, op);
    op = 'A';
    calculate(a, b, op);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./a.out 
10/20 = 0.50 
10+20 = 30  
$
```

W.r.t question-2:

```
char a[20] = {1,2,3,4,5,\n};
```

is not valid, instead it should actually be as follows

```
char a[20] = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '\n'};
```